# how to measure the read and write time on hdfs using job spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, ceph

I just started the work on the qualification of a big data platform, and I would like to have proposals on how to test the performance of reading and writing on hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the spark jobs for read and write operation then you can see the job time on application manager (localhost:50070) and if you are using spark-shell then you have to measure time manually or you can use time function.